# Accepting Hashmap as a body for the POST call

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I have to write a procedure which will accept body in  Hashmap format.
I have created HttpEntity with Hashmap values & headers.

```
public <T> void doPOSTRequest(String url, T body, HttpHeaders headers) throws JsonProcessingException {

    HttpEntity<T> request = new HttpEntity<T>(body,headers);
    System.out.println("Printing Request :" + request);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

    //Calling POST Method
    //response=restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,String.class);
     response=restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request,String.class);


    System.out.println(response);

}
```

I am facing below exception :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No
>   HttpMessageConverter for [java.util.HashMap]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:957)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:733)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
>     at Com.RESTRequest.doPOSTRequest(RESTRequest.java:39)   at
>   Com.GenericREST.main(GenericREST.java:30)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MultiValueMap` instead of Generic like this

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers);
```

Full block:

```
public <T> void doPOSTRequest(String url, T body, HttpHeaders headers) throws JsonProcessingException {
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(body,headers);
    System.out.println("Printing Request :" + request);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
    //Calling POST Method
    //response=restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,String.class);
     response=restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request,String.class);

    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But I am getting Map<String,object> as input parameter. I can't change that due to dependencies.

Comment: Well in that case pls look into content type being passed for POST request header W